# Grunt is not recognised : windows7 64-bit

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have installed npm and installed grunt, but when i run grunt, it says 'grunt' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

I done the below steps in command prompt

```
npm install

npm install -g grunt-cli
```

PATH variable and grunt folder are available but still i am not able to run grunt. 
Please provide me a solution for this

Comment: From [the docs](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started): "Note that installing grunt-cli does not install the Grunt task runner! "

Answer (score 1):

You have only installed the command line interface.

Use `npm install -g grunt` to install the actual program.